# Unmarshalling optional float64 field returns error on Go

Tags: xml, floating-point, go

The external API that my application is using, sometimes returns no values for one of the float64 fields. When that happens, I cannot unmarshal the rest of the document.

Here is the sample code in Go playground:

http://play.golang.org/p/Twv8b6KCtw

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/xml"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {

    type Result struct {
        XMLName xml.Name `xml:"Person"`
        Grade   float64  `xml:"grade"`
        Name    string   `xml:"name"`
    }

    data := `
        <Person>
            <grade/>
            <name>Jack</name>
        </Person>
    `
    var v Result
    err := xml.Unmarshal([]byte(data), &v)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("error: %v", err)
        return
    }
    fmt.Printf("name: %s\n", v.Name)

}
```

If I change float64 in line 12 to string, it will work. Any idea how I can get a workaround for this? Should I just define every field as string and do the conversion manually?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you have discovered a bug, <s>you should report it on the [issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/go/issues/list)</s>, I submitted a bug report [issue 8333](https://code.google.com/p/go/issues/detail?id=8333).

Now for the current problem, you have 2 options:

1. Use `string` type they do your own conversation to float on demand.
2. Remove the `<grade/>` tag completely and use `xml:"grade,omitempty"` in your struct.

Comment: Doing the conversion by my own defeats the whole point of defining all the fields in structs. I cannot really use omitempty option as the external API that I'm using is returning <grade/>. Maybe I should change Unmarshal() to ignore creating empty elements like that.

Comment: Well, you could define your conversation function on the struct or simply run your xml through `strings.Replace(xml_string, "<grade/>", "", -1)` but this is a bug.

Comment: Great. Looking forward to seeing it at the next release.

Answer (score 4):

To add to OneOfOne's solutions, you can also define your own `UnmarshalXML` method.

Example ([On play](http://play.golang.org/p/OxlrpATCn0)):

```
type Grade float64

func (g *Grade) UnmarshalXML(d *xml.Decoder, s xml.StartElement) error {
    for tok, err := d.Token(); err != io.EOF; tok, err = d.Token() {
        if chrdata, ok := tok.(xml.CharData); ok {
            f, err := strconv.ParseFloat(string(chrdata), 64)
            if err != nil {
                return err
            }
            *(*float64)(g) = f
        }
    }
    return nil
}

type Result struct {
    XMLName xml.Name `xml:"Person"`
    Grade   Grade    `xml:"grade"`
    Name    string   `xml:"name"`
}
```

This parses the `<grade>` tag by searching for `CharData` tokens in between and parsing them as float, leaving the grade at `0.0` when there is no value to be parsed.